# Install Subversion on Ubuntu with NGINX, not Apache

Tags: svn, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and I could like to install Subversion. I don't need http access to the files and I would like to use SSH.
The majority of the examples I've seen on how to install Subversion use Apache. I don't want to install Apache on my sever since I'm using NGINX. Can I just install Subversion without installing Apache? If yes, how? Thank you!

Comment: Better suited to Serverfault: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @OMG: Or Unix... (dots only to make it long enough)

Comment: First time I've heard of serverfault.com. Good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need HTTP access to your subversion repository, all you need to do is just install subversion and create a repository like this:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/repository
```

Then you can check out local copies directly:

```
svn co /path/to/repository /path/to/my/checkout
```

Or over ssh:

```
svn co svn+ssh://server/path/to/repository
```

If your packaging system is trying to install Apache with subversion, that is a packaging issue. However in Ubuntu, the subversion package does not require apache. Its requirements are:

```
Depends: libsvn1 (= 1.6.12dfsg-1ubuntu1), libapr1 (>= 1.2.7), libc6 (>= 2.4), libsasl2-2
Suggests: subversion-tools, db4.8-util, patch
```